# random.randint(2, 12) returns same results every time it's run in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have a script that generates 10 random numbers between 2 and 12:

```
repetition = 10
while repetition > 0:
    print(random.randint(2,12))
    repetition = repetition - 1
```

When this code is executed 10 random numbers are generated, but each time I execute the code the same 10 random numbers are generated. This happens even if I run the code on a different computer!

Comment: Can you add the result of your code to question too?

Comment: Some other part of your code must be seeding the random generator with a fixed value.

Comment: Is that the entirety of the code to reproduce the problem? `random` has a `seed` function which sets the starting point for the PRNG; if this is getting set prior to your calls, then the expected behavior is to get the same results, every time, even across different computers.

Comment: A little off topic, but judging by the range of 2 to 12 you might be simulating a pair of dice. If so, you should generate *two* random numbers in the range 1 to 6 and add them, otherwise your odds aren't going to be the same.

Comment: where are you running this from? I also cannot replate. It might help to add the full code.

Comment: Can you post a complete executable that does this? Something short.

Comment: also, that while loop is better expressed as:  for _ in range(10): print(random.randint(2,12))

Answer (score 3):

The first thing that you should understand is that computer generated random numbers are not really random. To generate a pseudo-random number, the computer uses a function that generates a number based on a previous value (more details in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation). The sequence of pseudo-random numbers depends on the first value passed to this function, known as **seed**.

By default in the `Random` class' constructor (`__init__`), used by Python's random module, the seed is defined by the operating system. This is usually based on the current system time. If you defined your own seed using the function `random.seed` your results will be deterministic. You will always get the same values in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while doing

```
from random import randint
randint(0, 10)
```

now I just do

```
import random
```

and then

```
random.randint(0, 10)
```

and it works

Comment: no that can't be.. i'm already using import random and still always same result when looping

Answer (score 1):

You can set seed value dependent on the time. Seed value will change with every call.

```
import random
import time
random.seed(time.clock())
repetition = 10
while repetition > 0:
   print(random.randint(2,12))
   repetition = repetition - 1
```

Comment: This would now be `time.perf_counter()` or `time.process_time()` per [the removal of .clock()](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#api-and-feature-removals)

Answer (score -1):

#Try numpy:

import numpy as np

np.random.randint(low=1,high=7,size=10)

#Mostlikely, it will give you different results after each run.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem.

```
from random import randint

randint(2, 12)
```

That did it for me.