# Python random.randint() keeps returning 0 after certain time

Tags: python, random

I was trying to get 3 random numbers within range in python without replacement. I did this

```
rand_lst = []

while(True):
    rand = random.randint(0, length-1 )
    if(len(rand_lst) == 3):
         break
    if(rand not in rand_lst):
         rand_lst.append(rand)
```

This code is inside a for loop. This returns only 0 and thus an infinite loop. I also tried numpy.random.randint but some how random is keeping track of previously generated numbers and I endup with value error.

Comment: What is `length`?

Comment: You may want to look into `random.sample`:  specifically, try `random.sample(range(length), 3)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying putting `print(length)` right before your `while True`. You'll almost certainly find that the value of `length` is not what you expect it to be. (It's probably 0 or 1, when you want it to be 3 at least.)

Comment: True, I did that any somehow length is 1 which is  odd!! Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you correctly,
you want something like this:

```
import random
rand_lst = []
length = 10

while(True):
    rand = random.randint(0, length-1 )
    if(len(rand_lst) == 3):
         break
    if(rand not in rand_lst):
         rand_lst.append(rand)
print(rand_lst)
```

this way "length" has a value and will not throw an error

Answer (score 0):

Explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33806926/8386640

Use random.sample. Here is code.

```
import random

rand_lst = []
length = 3

while(len(rand_lst) < 3):
    rand_lst.append(random.sample(range(length), 3))
print rand_lst
```

Comment: BTW, it is a prime example of misused `break` - instead of using conditional break inside a loop, `while len(rand_lst) < 3:` should have been used.

Comment: Your `while` loop is unnecessary. `rand_lst = random.sample(range(length), 3)` already generates exactly what the OP needs, all by itself.

Comment: @Błotosmętek thanks.