# Python repeat random integer in while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to code player and mob attacks for a text based RPG game I am making, I have randomint set up for player and mob hitchance and crit chance but I can't figure out how to get a new integer for them every time I restart the loop, it uses the same integer it got the first time it entered the loop.

```
### GAME VALUES ###
class roll_dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spawn = random.randint(1,100)
        self.escape = random.randint(1,100)
        self.playercrit = random.randint(1,100)
        self.playerhitchance = random.randint(1,100)
        self.mobcrit = random.randint(1,100)
        self.mobhitchance = random.randint(1,100)
roll = roll_dice()    


### ORC SPAWN ###
if fight_walk.lower() == 'fight':
    orcMobSpawn()
    while True:
        fight_orc = input(">>> ")
        if fight_orc.lower() == 'a':

            ### PLAYER ATTACK ###
            while True:
                roll.playercrit
                roll.playerhitchance
                if roll.playercrit <= 10 and roll.playerhitchance >= 6:
                    print("You crit orc for",str(userPlayer.atk * 2),"damage!")
                    orcMob.hp = orcMob.hp - userPlayer.atk * 2
                    print("Orc HP:",orcMob.hp)
                    break
                elif roll.playercrit >= 11 and roll.playerhitchance >= 6:
                    print("You hit orc for",str(userPlayer.atk),"damage!")
                    orcMob.hp = orcMob.hp - userPlayer.atk
                    print("Orc HP:",orcMob.hp)
                    break
                elif roll.playercrit >= 11 and roll.playerhitchance <= 5:
                    print("You missed!")
                    break
                elif roll.playercrit <= 10 and roll.playerhitchance <= 5:
                    print("You missed!")
                    break
                elif orcMob.hp <= 0 and userPlayer.hp >= 1:
                    print("Your HP:",str(userPlayer.hp))
                    print("You win!")
                    break
                elif userPlayer.hp <= 0:
                    print("You died!")
                    exit()

            ### ORC ATTACK ###
            while True:
                roll.mobcrit
                roll.mobhitchance
                if orcMob.hp <= 0 and userPlayer.hp >= 1:
                    break
                if roll.mobcrit <= 5 and roll.mobhitchance >= 25:
                    print("\nOrc crit for",str(orcMob.atk * 2),"damage!")
                    userPlayer.hp = userPlayer.hp - orcMob.atk * 2
                    print("Your HP:",str(userPlayer.hp))
                    break
                elif roll.mobcrit >= 5 and roll.mobhitchance >= 25:
                    print("\nOrc hit for",str(orcMob.atk),"damage!")
                    userPlayer.hp = userPlayer.hp - orcMob.atk
                    print("Your HP",str(userPlayer.hp))
                    break
                elif roll.mobcrit <= 5 and roll.mobhitchance <= 25:
                    print("Orc missed!")
                    print("Your HP:",str(userPlayer.hp))
                    break
                elif roll.mobcrit >= 5 and roll.mobhitchance <= 25:
                    print("Orc missed!")
                    print("Your HP:",str(userPlayer.hp))
                    break
        if orcMob.hp <= 0 and userPlayer.hp >= 1:
            break
        elif orcMob.hp >= 1:
            continue
```

Comment: I think maybe repeat of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33806022/random-randint2-12-returns-same-results-every-time-its-run-in-python

Comment: Not 100% sure what your asking but assuming roll.playercrit and roll.playerhitchance are variables, to get a new random number you need to generate again at that part of the code. eg. `roll.playerhitchance = random.randint()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `roll_dice` class. You have the values defined when the class initializes, but then you never update them again. Therefore `self.escape` or `self.spawn` will always be the same value after the program starts. The easiest way to solve your problem without rewriting much would be to make another instance of `roll_dice()` every time you want to roll the dice. Something like:

```
### GAME VALUES ###
class roll_dice:
    def __init__(self):
        self.spawn = random.randint(1,100)
        self.escape = random.randint(1,100)
        self.playercrit = random.randint(1,100)
        self.playerhitchance = random.randint(1,100)
        self.mobcrit = random.randint(1,100)
        self.mobhitchance = random.randint(1,100)
# roll = roll_dice() # you don't need to make an instance here


### ORC SPAWN ###
if fight_walk.lower() == 'fight':
    orcMobSpawn()
    while True:
        fight_orc = input(">>> ")
        if fight_orc.lower() == 'a':

            ### PLAYER ATTACK ###
            while True:
                roll = roll_dice() # make a new instance with each loop
                roll.playercrit
                roll.playerhitchance
                if roll.playercrit <= 10 and roll.playerhitchance >= 6:
                    print("You crit orc for",str(userPlayer.atk * 2),"damage!")
                    orcMob.hp = orcMob.hp - userPlayer.atk * 2
                    print("Orc HP:",orcMob.hp)
                    break
                elif roll.playercrit >= 11 and roll.playerhitchance >= 6:
                    print("You hit orc for",str(userPlayer.atk),"damage!")
                    orcMob.hp = orcMob.hp - userPlayer.atk
                    print("Orc HP:",orcMob.hp)
                    break
                elif roll.playercrit >= 11 and roll.playerhitchance <= 5:
                    print("You missed!")
                    break
                elif roll.playercrit <= 10 and roll.playerhitchance <= 5:
                    print("You missed!")
                    break
                elif orcMob.hp <= 0 and userPlayer.hp >= 1:
                    print("Your HP:",str(userPlayer.hp))
                    print("You win!")
                    break
                elif userPlayer.hp <= 0:
                    print("You died!")
                    exit()

            ### ORC ATTACK ###
```

Answer (score 1):

Use functions like

```
import random
for x in range(10):
    print random.randint(1,101)
```

use a array around  for a max 100 people and generate random digits to add in your code.

You can also use a array to create random umber structure and then use the numbers to be shuffled and added as you create them

```
from random import *

items = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
shuffle(items)
print items
```